# Array prototype and literal

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
Array.prototype.slice === [].slice  // output true
console.log(Array.prototype) // output  []
```

Why the following condition is false (taking above statements in count)

```
Array.prototype === [] //output (false)
```

Comment: The methods are the same because they point to the same function, the objects are different, not the same object, `[] !== []`

Comment: I guess you want to learn about the prototype chain: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: If you would like to know more about prototype in JavaScript and constructor functions then maybe the following answer can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 It doesn't cover Array.prototype being an instance of Array (I didn't know that before) but explains what prototype is and how constructor functions can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of memory location.

For example, let's say you have two objects, `{A}` and `{B}`. Yes, both belong to the `Object.prototype`; however, that does not mean `{A} === {B}`. They don't necessarily carry the same properties or exist in the same memory location.

Similarly, `Array.prototype` creates a blank array `[]`, much like typing the array literal, `[]`, does. These two calls are distinct, however, in that `Array.prototype` returns the be-all and end-all of all arrays, whereas `[]` just instantiates a new array in memory. They both "return" the same thing in the console, but are actually quite different. This is why `Array.prototype === Array.prototype` returns `true`, while `[] === []` returns `false`. The MDN article on ["Inheritance and the prototype chain"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) does a good job at explaining how `.prototype` works in JavaScript.

So why exactly does `Array.prototype === []` return false, when `Array.prototype === Array.prototype` returns true, considering `Array.prototype` returns `[]`? Well, this would be the same as saying `var arr1 = []` and `var arr2 = []` were equal; they're not.

For example, when you have two arrays:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [2,3,4];
```

You don't check for equality with `if (arr1 === arr2)`, as that would only tell you if they existed in the same memory location. Instead, you loop through and compare the elements. It's the same concept for `Array.prototype === []`, except the arrays have no elements.

The reason `Array.prototype.slice === [].slice` returns `true` is because it's comparing two functions, which both happen to be `.slice`, meaning they occupy and reference the same memory location. It only makes sense that they are equal because they are indeed the same thing.

```
console.log([].slice);
// returns:
/*
    function slice() {
        [native code]
    }
*/
// console.log(Array.prototype.slice) returns the same thing.
```

Try `Array.prototype.slice === [].splice`—it returns false. Two different functions in two different locations. What about `Array.prototype.slice() === [].slice()`? It returns false? What? Why?

Because each side of the equality operator references two different memory locations. You called `.slice` on two different arrays, so now you're comparing two different slices of two different arrays, hence the `false` return.

Comment: Please edit.  You are correct that `[]===[]` is false but the first sentence of your third paragraph is incorrect if I understand it correctly. "Array.prototype" does not "create a blank array  with the same effect as typing `[]`. There is one array prototype object. So `Array.prototype===Array.prototype` evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @mheiber This is true. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.prototype` is an array itself and `console.log` for any empty array (in Chrome...) outputs `[]`.

The strict equality operator (`===`) compares references between the two arrays and `Array.prototype` does not have the same reference as your array literal.

Comment: "`Array.prototype` is an array itself" `Array.prototype instanceof Array` -> false

Comment: @guest `instanceof` compares prototypes and I guess using it on the prototype itself produces some weird results, but calling `Object.prototype.toString.call(Array.prototype)` outputs `"[object Array]"`. Also `Array.isArray(Array.prototype)` outputs `true`.

Comment: @guest: *"The Array prototype object is itself an array; its [[Class]] is "Array", and it has a length property (whose initial value is +0) and the special [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method described in 15.4.5.1."* http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4

Comment: Thanks for the link, Felix. Turns out to be an *array* (lowercase a, I guess) an object needs to have its [[Class]] internal property set to "Array" (http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.3.2). This is different from being an *Array object* in the OO model.

Comment: @guest From the MDN: `The instanceof operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.` Array.prototype doesn't have Array.prototype in its prototype chain. Similarly,  `fooPrototype instnaceof Foo` is `false` in this example: `Foo=function(){};fooPrototype={};Foo.prototype=fooPrototype;fooPrototype instanceof Foo;`

Comment: @guest: I guess JavaScript is just... different :)

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into prototype inheritance stuff ...

Two objects can be different, but some of their properties can reference the same thing.

```
var same = {};
var a = {test: same};
var b = {test: same};
console.log(a.test === b.test); // true
console.log(a === b); // false
a.name = 'a';
console.log(b.name); // undefined, because b is a different object
a.same.name = 'arnold';
console.log(b.same.name); // arnold
```